# PHP image if else CSS

Tags: php, html, css, image, if-statement

I'm wondering how I could echo an image depending on a css style?
To be more clear: My navigation is transparent, if I scroll down the navigation sticks to the top of the screen but gets a white background.
My logo can be used in gray and white. When transparent its hard to read in gray, so I use the white version.
When the navigation becomes white, the white logo isn't visible so I want it to change to the gray logo.
Is there a way to change an image with an if / else?
Something like if navigation is white echo graylogo, else echo whitelogo

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can do this entirely with JavaScript. Probably by checking how far down the user has scrolled the page.

Comment: Not with PHP; PHP can't listen to browser events directly so once the page is rendered and passed to the browser it's outside of PHP's domain. Like @durbnpoisn implied, whatever event is changing your nav's background to white can also be used to change the src of your logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I was you, i'd put the 2 images in my code, then, you'd simply have to do show the logo depending on the class. Example:

```
<div class="nav">
  <img src=".." class="white-img">
  <img src=".." class="black-img">
</div>
```

Then the css:

```
.nav.white .white-img{
   display: none;
}
.nav.black .black-img{
   display: none;
}
```

Then, using PHP when you create your page, you could set the right class to your nav element, or using javascript if it's event driven. (user click, user scroll or etc)